# SceneKit - Max 8 lights per scene?

Tags: scenekit

The SceneKit documentation eludes to the fact that I can only have 8 SCNLights in my scene, but it mentions per node which wonders If I can do anything to get more than 8?

Any ideas? or am I stuck?

"SceneKit only uses up to eight light sources per node when rendering, ignoring any additional lights."

from: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNLight_Class/

Answer (score 1):

that's the eight *nearest* lights for a given node

Comment: ah! So splitting my floor up into multiple nodes should negate the problem.

Comment: @Chris Splitting up into multiple nodes and using categoryBitMask didn’t work for me (2023). The limit still is 8 per scene.